# Set previously selected value in Dropdown box using PHP

Tags: php, html, select, web, dropdown

So, what I'm trying to achieve that after the user hits submit, the dropdown retains the value that the user have chosen. This is my code for the dropdown, I understand that I have to `selected = 'selected'`, but I couldn't figure out how it fits in my code.

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {     // output data of each row
    while($row_branch = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $menu_branch .= "<option value='".$row_branch["0"]."'>" . 
        $row_branch["0"]. "</option>";
    }
} 
echo $menu_branch;
```

Comment: you are creating another select-box based on first-one selected value?

Comment: yup, im doing that, after submitting the first drop down value, the second drop down will be populated with values based on the first choice.

Comment: and you are  using POST method or GET method?Also what is the name of first-select box?

Comment: i used POST method to get the value after submission

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if i understand right:

```
 // $yourvalue is previous dropdown value

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  // output data of each row
 while($row_branch = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     if ($row_branch["0"] == $yourvalue)
         $selected = "selected";
     else 
         $selected = "";
     $menu_branch .= "<option value='".$row_branch["0"]."' $selected>" . 
     $row_branch["0"]. "</option>";
  }
}

echo $menu_branch;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just add selected = selected inside the loop because every option will be selected.
You might need the **if statement** to select the option of your choice.
For example:

```
 if($row_branch["0"] == 'bar'){
   $menu_branch .= "<option value='".$row_branch["0"]."' selected>" . 
             $row_branch["0"]. "</option>";
}else{
   $menu_branch .= "<option value='".$row_branch["0"]."'>" . 
             $row_branch["0"]. "</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the user select an option, Where you submit this information?

If this information return from a database

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
 // output data of each row
 while($row_branch = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     $select = ($row_branch["0"]==$value_db)? "selected='selected'" : "";
     $menu_branch .= "<option value='".$row_branch["0"]."' $select>" . 
     $row_branch["0"]. "</option>";
  }
}
```

Comment: thanx for the answer, the information is submmited to the database.